# Mean normalization different versions of code

Tags: python, pandas

I want to mean normalize my data frame, when I implement the first version of code I am getting the normalized values, but when I implement version 2 I am getting an error called `stop iteration`. `["1B","2B","3B","HR","BB"]` are columns in my data frame.

**Version 1:**

```
def meanNormalizeRates(df):
        subRates = df[["1B","2B","3B","HR","BB"]]
        df[["1B","2B","3B","HR","BB"]] = subRates - subRates.mean(axis=0)
        return df

stats = stats.groupby('yearID').apply(meanNormalizeRates)
stats.head()
```

**Version 2:**

```
 def mean(df):
    for val in ["1B","2B","3B","HR","BB"]:
          stats[val] = stats[val] -stats[val].mean(axis=0)

stats = stats.groupby('yearID').apply(mean)

stats.head()
```

I couldnt understand the difference between the two versions.

A good example

```
data = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada'],
'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002],
'pop': [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9],
'gate' : [9, 7, 4,6, 9]}

frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
frame.head()
```

**Version 1.1**

```
def std(df):
    temp = df[['gate', 'pop']]
    df[['gate', 'pop']] = temp - temp.mean(axis=0)
    return df
frame.groupby('year').apply(std)

    gate    pop state   year
0   9   1.5 Ohio    2000
1   7   1.7 Ohio    2001
2   4   3.6 Ohio    2002
3   6   2.4 Nevada  2001
4   9   2.9 Nevada  2002
```

**Version 1.2**

```
def mean(df):
    for val in ['gate', 'pop']:
        df[val] = df[val]- df[val].mean(axis=0)

frame.groupby('year').apply(mean)

error: stop iteration
```

Comment: Can you try to include some [reproducible example data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/1222578)? It's a bit hard to tell why your results might differ without it.

Comment: @Marius - I have given an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so because you don't have a return statement in your `mean()` function (in example 1.2), that function just returns `None` for every group. The `StopIteration` error you get isn't all that clear, but what is happening is:

- `apply()` calls your `mean()` function on every group.
- Each of those calls returns `None`.
- The results get put into a list, so here it's a list of all
  `None`s
- As part of trying to stitch the results back together,
  `apply()` tries to find the non-`None` values in the list,
  which throws a `StopIteration` exception.

So basically you can reproduce the error by doing:

```
eg_list = [None, None, None]
v = next(v for v in eg_list if v is not None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-93b31b7a51e4> in <module>()
----> 1 v = next(v for v in eg_list if v is not None)
```

All that might be too much detail though- the takeaway is that when you're
using `apply()`, you shouldn't really be doing all your changes within the
function you're applying- you should be returning a result from the function
and assigning them back to the dataframe, like:

```
# The lambda here will return the relevant values of gate and pop,
# and we just assign them wherever we want in the dataframe.
# Could be new columns, could be existing ones
frame[['gate', 'pop']] = frame.groupby('year')[['gate', 'pop']].apply(
    lambda group: group - group.mean(axis=0))
```

Comment: isnt frame.groupby('year')[['gate', 'pop']]  and frame.groupby('year') are equal ??

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do things within the function, it's just not really how groupby and apply work. `frame.groupby('year')[['gate', 'pop']]` is almost the same as `frame.groupby('year')`, it just excludes the state column.